# Uso de STI(Single Table Inheritance) no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modelo-relacional

- Supondo um projeto no rails com os modelos Pecuária, Agricultura,
  Piscicultura e Benfeitoria.
- Sendo que estes herdam as propriedades de um modelo chamado Atividade
  e são considerados tipos de Atividade.
- Os modelos não precisão herdar métodos ou comportamentos específicos,
  no caso apenas os de acesso as propriedades herdadas
- Porém alguns modelos possuem propriedades além das herdadas e outros
  não, por exemplo Agricultura , além das herdadas, possui as
  propriedades GrupoAgricola e TipoDeAgricultura.

Tendo isto em mente vem minhas dúvidas:
 1ª É um cenário propício para o uso da técnica STI(Single Table Inheritance)?
 2ª No caso dos modelos que possuem apenas as propriedades herdadas, ha como evitar a criação de uma nova  tabela ou modelo de persistência?.

Comment: Já experimentou modelar com composição ao invés de Herança?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os modelos vão herdar um número considerável de atributos e vão implementar comportamento comum, sim, é uma boa opção.

Usando postgres 9.4 com rails 4.2 dá pra fazer de forma bem transparente.

Recomendo a leitura destes posts para uma idéia de como implementar:

https://netguru.co/blog/renewed-life-for-sti-with-postgresql-json-type

http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: porém o fato de eu querer evitar que alguns tipos de atividades sejam persistidos, como devo fazer?, apenas não criar o Model correspondente mas incluir na lista de tipos, por exemplo 'def Atividade.tipos %w{Tipo1 Tipo2 Tipo3}' porém não criar o arquivo tipo3.rb?

Comment: Não entendi, pq não seriam persistidos?

Comment: Porque pelo oque eu entendi usando STI todas propriedades herdadas do 'Base' são salvas na tabela referente á base ex: o modelo X possui as propriedades x1, x2 e x3 os modelos XA e XB estendem X porém o modelo XA também possui as propriedades xa1, xa2 e xa3, e XB não possui nenhuma além. Contudo são criados 3 tabelas a tabela x com os campos (id, x1, x2 , x3, created_at e modified_at) a tabela xa com os campos (id, xa1, xa2 , xa3, reated_at e modified_at) e a tabela xb s com os campos (id, reated_at e modified_at). Porém não vejo a necessidade de criar xb

Comment: Não, nao é criadas tabelas para XA nem XB, todos modelos usam a mesma tabela.

Comment: Leia os links que passei na minha resposta, lá ensina a gravar os campos "extras" em uma campo json.